# How to safely preview shell's "parameter meddling"? (i.e Token recognition + wordexp)

Tags: shell, posix

Is there a way to preview "how the [shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) would interprete the user input (in terms of [Token recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03), and [wordexp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html#))"?

Moreover would a shell function `preview () { printf '%s\n' "$*"; }` be such safe and adequate way to preview what parameters would have been supplied to a shell-builtin/shell-function/program?

Lastly is there a similar appraoch to preview the "parameter meddling" (i.e Token Recoginition + wordexp) in the more complex cases of compound commands?

Having a way preview what might be subsummed as "shell's parameter meddling" would allow to demonstrate the somewhat obscured role/part of the shell to novices in an attempt to prevent `touch ./-r; rm *` mishaps ;)

Comment: No shell that I know of has an interactive "are you sure"-mode. Learning how the shell actually works and using it defensively (especially with regards to user-supplied data) seems to be the best approach to avoid mishaps.

Comment: You might get something useful if you replaced `"$*"` with `"$@"`.